# POST Variable Lost on Submit

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, variables, post

I have form with a submit button that changes value depending on the page.  When the submit button is pressed, I need that value to do some data validation.  However, the value is being lost somewhere in the process.

- I did a value check on the button using 'click' in jQuery that fires before the 'submit' of the data.  The value is correct.
- On the page load, I tried checking the POST variable value and it is gone.

  - EXCEPT in the following situations:

    1. If I do NOT use the POST variable in any way, such as 'if' statements.  Or assign its value to a variable.  If I do any of those things, the value is lost does not even show up when I check for its value at the top of the page.

       2.If I leave one of the required fields in the form blank.

I should note that this is a Wordpress site. I know people are going to be asking for code, but the page is quite long, so I will try to get some code here soon.

Comment: example code??? Yeah, not from the complete site. only from the form!

Comment: Part of the problem is, when I cut out some of the code, it works.  Even in the PHP code.  So, not sure how short I can get it down to and still have it do the fail.

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons do not submit their values, add an `input type='hidden'` with the value

Comment: Fail. Submit-buttons will submit their values. **All** form objects will submit their value if their have an `name` attribute. It's irrelevant if youre using `<input>`, `<button>`, `<textarea>` or other form elements. The **NAME ATTRIBUTE** is crucial!

Answer (score 0):

Add an input hidden and set its value to the value of the submit button right before pressing the submit button:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#form', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $('#form input[name="submit_value"]').val($(this).find('input:submit').val());

   $(this).submit();
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="submit_value" />
   <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: What's the point? Whya you dont using `<input type="submit" name="submit_value" value="Submit" />` ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the error.  Turns out it didn't have to do with the POST.

There was an extra line in the code that kept resetting a variable back to the initial value.

Sorry for the trouble and thanks for the help anyway!!